# I don't understand the proof of Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying this proof of Schwarz lemma on page 4
http://pagine.dm.unipi.it/abate/libri/libriric/files/IterationThTautMan1-1.pdf

I don't understand how the author uses the maximum principle to say that $|g(z)|\le \sup_{|w|=r}|g(w)|$

Can you help me please?

Comment: What do you know about the maximum modulus principle?

Comment: The principle states that, if $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorfic function, U is a open and connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and exixts $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z_0)|=\sup_{z\in U}|f(z)|$, then f is constant.

Comment: Now apply that to the function $g$.

Comment: How? In the hypothesis i need the existence of $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|g(z_0)|= \sup_{w \in \Delta} |g(w)|$. How do i know it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|z|=r$ is a closed disk it is compact, so the function |g(z)| must attain a maximum here. If it attains the maximum on the interior of the disk it is constant. In either way $g$ attains its max on the boundary.